# OSRM Map Matching Output explanation

Tags: open-source-routing-machine

I am trying to understand why the output includes None in tracepoints. What do these mean?

> [**None, None, None,** {u'waypoint_index': 0, u'name': u'West Washington Street',

And then the algorithm would return a coordinate sometimes without a street name. Are these erroneous output?

> {u'waypoint_index': 26, **u'name': u''**, u'hint': u'eWK6g____382AAAAjwAAAAAAAAB-AAAADQAAACQAAAAAAAAAHwAAAJo5AAB55FH5-qL-AY3kUfkRo_4BAAAvE3jrEvY=', u'matchings_index': 0, u'location': **[-112.073607, 33.465082]**, u'alternatives_count': 0}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Referring to your second question: an empty street name is returned when the road where your original point snapped to has no name. In your example, the point is on a small service road without a name.

Your first question has been answered here: https://github.com/Project-OSRM/osrm-backend/issues/4871